# Get list of webforms that can be created by the current user

Tags: 8, entities, webforms, users

Testing Webform in Drupal 8, I've found something strange when trying to get the list of the available webforms that a user can **create**.

My test environment: I've created a role, a user that belongs to that role and 3 webforms. In the "*Access*" tab of each of the webforms I've unchecked "*Anonymous user*" and "*Authenticated User*" and allowed access only to "*Administrator*" in 2 of the webforms. In the last one, I gave "create" access to my specific role.

Then, for testing purposes I created a rest service with the following code:

```
public function get() 
{
    // Load all the available entities
    $entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->loadMultiple(NULL);

    // Check the access of the current user to each of the entities 
    $forms = array();
    foreach( $entities as $entity_id => $entity )
    {
       $forms[] = array( "$entity_id" => $entity->access('create', NULL) );
    }

    return new ModifiedResourceResponse($forms);
}
```

I expected to get:

```
[{"webform1":false},{"webform2":false},{"webform3":true}]
```

But I get:

```
[{"webform1":false},{"webform2":false},{"webform3":false}]
```

In fact, I returned the `$entity` object as JSON and I found that the entity references the following permissions: "create", "view_any", "update_any", "delete_any", "purge_any", "view_own", "update_own", "delete_own". If I expand the tree, then I can see that inside the "create" permission of my webform3 entity, the permissions are properly referenced (Object->access->create->Roles->My Role is present only in the last form).

But the `->access('create')` function is always returning false. The same goes for "view_any" and the other permissions. The only permission that returns true for all the forms is "view".

Is there any way that I can do this? :

```
    $entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->loadMultiple(NULL);
    $forms = array();
    foreach( $entities as $entity_id => $entity )
    {
       if( $entity->access('create', NULL) ) 
       {
           $forms[] = $entityid;
       }
    }
    return new ModifiedResourceResponse($forms);
```

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll autoanswer my question :)

By grep-ing inside Webform source code I found that the permission name is not "create", but "submission_create", even if `dpm($entity)` is referencing "create".

```
$ grep -r "access" * | grep submission_create
webform_node.routing.yml:    entity_access: 'webform.submission_create'
Webform.php:                 if (!$webform || !$webform->access('submission_create')) {
(...)
```

So, this works as expected:

```
$entities = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('webform')->loadMultiple(NULL);
$forms = array();
foreach( $entities as $entity_id => $entity )
{
    if( $entity->access('submission_create', NULL) ) {
        $forms[] = $entity_id;
    }
}
```

It returns only the webforms that you are entitled to send submissions to.